# Meteor call result has undefined instance variables

Tags: javascript, typescript, meteor, meteor-methods

The server has a Meteor `Method` that returns a `GiftList` object that contains a `Gift` set.

The client has a Meteor `Call` that prints out the result. The `Gift` set is undefined even though it is initialised and sent by the server. The instance variables don't seem to be included in the response even though the server has sent it.

**Gift List**

```
import {Gift} from "../gift/Gift";

export class GiftList {

    private _id: number;
    private _personName:string;
    private _user: User;

    private _gifts: Set<Gift>;

    get id(): number {
        return this._id;
    }

    set id(value: number) {
        this._id = value;
    }

    get personName(): string {
        return this._personName;
    }

    set personName(value: string) {
        this._personName = value;
    }

    get user(): User {
        return this._user;
    }

    set user(value: User) {
        this._user = value;
    }

    get gifts(): Set<Gift> {
        return this._gifts;
    }

    set gifts(value: Set<Gift>) {
        this._gifts = value;
    }
}
```

**Gift**

```
import {GiftList} from "../giftlist/GiftList";

export class Gift {

    private _id: number;
    private _name: string;
    private _description: string;
    private _isPrivate: boolean;
    private _cost: number;

    private _giftList: GiftList;

    get id(): number {
        return this._id;
    }

    set id(value: number) {
        this._id = value;
    }

    get name(): string {
        return this._name;
    }

    set name(value: string) {
        this._name = value;
    }

    get description(): string {
        return this._description;
    }

    set description(value: string) {
        this._description = value;
    }

    get isPrivate(): boolean {
        return this._isPrivate;
    }

    set isPrivate(value: boolean) {
        this._isPrivate = value;
    }

    get cost(): number {
        return this._cost;
    }

    set cost(value: number) {
        this._cost = value;
    }

    get giftList(): GiftList {
        return this._giftList;
    }

    set giftList(value: GiftList) {
        this._giftList = value;
    }
}
```

**Server - Meteor Method**

```
Meteor.methods({
    "getGiftLists": function (): GiftList[] {
        const giftList: GiftList =  new GiftList();
        giftList.gifts = new Set();

        const gift: Gift = new Gift();
        gift.name= "Example gift";
        gift.description = "Description of gift";
        giftList.gifts.add(gift);

        // I've printed the value here and the gift list definitely contains gifts as expected. 
        return [giftList]
    }
})
```

**Client - Meteor Call**

```
Meteor.call("getGiftLists", {}, (err: any, res: GiftList[]) => {
    if (err) {
        alert(err);
    } else {
        console.dir(res); // Defined 
        console.log(res.length) // 1
        console.dir(res[0].gifts); // Undefined
        callback(res);
    }
});
```

**Question**

Why is the `Gift` set undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that Metoer's EJSON doesn't know how to serialize a `Set` to be sent to the client. EJSON provides a way to define new types and how they should be serialized and de-serialized. Have a look at the EJSON docs.

https://docs.meteor.com/api/ejson.html

Comment: That would make a lot more sense! I'll try using an array tomorrow. Should errors be thrown in cases like this?

Comment: I would say that it should probably throw errors. The fact that it doesn't may be due to the fact that Maps and Sets were not part of the ECMAScript spec at the time when this code was written. Might be a good bug report/feature request.